# using two different IPv4 with Docker (using venet0)

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu, network-programming, ipv4

I'm running an Ubuntu server VPS with Docker image containers,
which provides me 2 external IPv4 addresses within the interface venet0.
venet0 has got 2 sub v-interfaces: venet0:0 and venet0:1 (each with different IPv4 address);

is it possible that each docker image will use different venet? and then it will have different IPv4 for in/out traffic ?

ifconfig:

> docker0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
> inet 172.17.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.17.255.255
> ether 02:42:6e:1b:78:dd  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
> RX packets 300  bytes 40314 (40.3 KB)
> RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
> TX packets 279  bytes 155791 (155.7 KB)
> TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
>
> lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
> inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
> loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
> RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
> RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
> TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
> TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
>
> venet0: flags=211<UP,BROADCAST,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP>  mtu 1500
> inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.255.255.255  broadcast 0.0.0.0  destination 127.0.0.1
> unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 0  (UNSPEC)
> RX packets 2535  bytes 280255 (280.2 KB)
> RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
> TX packets 3514  bytes 368638 (368.6 KB)
> TX errors 0  dropped 1 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
>
> venet0:0: flags=211<UP,BROADCAST,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP>  mtu 1500
> inet xx.xx.xx.xx  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast xx.xx.xx.xx  destination xx.xx.xx.xx
> unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 0  (UNSPEC)
>
> venet0:1: flags=211<UP,BROADCAST,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP>  mtu 1500
> inet xx.yy.yy.yy  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast xx.yy.yy.yy  destination xx.yy.yy.yy
> unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 0  (UNSPEC)
>
> veth3e60e5d: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
> ether fe:73:1e:7d:30:0a  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
> RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
> RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
> TX packets 6  bytes 252 (252.0 B)
> TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
>
> veth83488a2: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
> ether 0e:11:e7:a6:8d:47  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
> RX packets 300  bytes 44514 (44.5 KB)
> RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
> TX packets 279  bytes 155791 (155.7 KB)
> TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

ip link:

> 1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN
> mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
> link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00 2: venet0: <BROADCAST,POINTOPOINT,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state
> UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default
> link/void 3: docker0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP mode DEFAULT group default
> link/ether 02:42:6e:1b:78:dd brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff 5: veth3e60e5d@if4: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc
> noqueue master docker0 state UP mode DEFAULT group default
> link/ether fe:73:1e:7d:30:0a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0 7: veth83488a2@if6: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc
> noqueue master docker0 state UP mode DEFAULT group default
> link/ether 0e:11:e7:a6:8d:47 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*The solution that I have found and it is working properly is:*

```
# Step 1
# Creating 2 different local networks (nw1 & nw2)
# and then route it via the desired IP addresses
sudo docker network create --driver bridge --subnet=172.18.0.2/16 --ip-range=172.18.0.2/16 nw1
sudo iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -p all -s 172.18.0.2/16 ! -o bridge -j SNAT --to-source FIRST_IPv4

sudo docker network create --driver bridge --subnet=172.19.0.2/16 --ip-range=172.19.0.2/16 nw2
sudo iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -p all -s 172.19.0.2/16 ! -o bridge -j SNAT --to-source SECOND_IPv4



# Step 2
# run the docker with '--net'
docker run -dt --name my_docker_name1 --net=nw1--restart=unless-stopped docker_image_name
docker run -dt --name my_docker_name2 --net=nw2--restart=unless-stopped docker_image_name
```